# The computer dead after upgrading ubuntu

Tags: boot, upgrade, system-installation

In the middle of upgrading my Ubuntu installation to the latest version, my computer turned off (the battery ran out), and now my computer doesn't work - even when I try to run the system from boot CD!

What can I do to resolve this issue?

Comment: please explain more. Can you see Grub Bootloader ?

Comment: where does it hang exactly?

Comment: I guess that is your fault. You should always plug your computer in and make sure it stays fully charged while upgrading any important piece of software, or performing edits to your disk. Anyway, you should provide more information like what OnlyMAJ and Stefano Mtangoo are asking.